# CoreNFC not detecting MiFare tag

Tags: ios, nfc

Sooo, I've read all over the internet about the limitations of MiFare tags, but I've also read a few posts about [successes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572827/detect-iso-iec-14443-mifare-ultralight-or-classic-nfc-cards-with-corenfc). Furthermore, my confusion intensifies from the fact that the Shortcuts automation *does* read the tag, but Apple's [example project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app) doesn't (even if I change all `NFCNDEFReader...` to `NFCTagReader...`). The session initialises properly, but neither `didDetect`, nor `didInvalidateWithError` ever get called.

Any ideas or tips?